# Does adding a compact operator change the symbol of a pseudodifferential operator?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, pseudo-differential-operators

Suppose $X$ is a non-compact manifold. Let $P$ be an order-$0$ pseudodifferential operator on $X$ and $f:L^2(X)\rightarrow L^2(X)$ a compact operator. I'm wondering:

1) Is $P + f$ always a pseudodifferential operator?

2) If so, does it have the same principal symbol as $P$?

Many thanks.

Comment: This would imply that any compact operator is $\Psi$DO. This is not the case, since, for instance, the kernel of a $\Psi$DO is smooth outside the diagonal. So simply take a kernel which is not smooth outside the diagonal, but $L^2$ and you get a compact operator which is not $\Psi$DO.

Comment: I see, that answers the first part. As for the second part, do you know if theres exists a compact pseudodifferential operators of non-negative order?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96925/when-a-pseudo-differential-operators-to-be-compact